# Aggregated assets from demo projects in UE4

Tags: assets, unreal-4

Unreal engine allows you to download demo projects under the "Learn" tab of their launcher.

**How do I access the resources and assets used in these projects in an aggregate form?**

To put it simply, there are textures and meshes and such that i would obviously like to utilize in my projects. These assets do not however seem to be readily available for use in any and all projects. How do i get them all in one place so i can access them?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should note that i am aware of the "Hard way" of doing it, im kinda just hoping there is a better solution...

EDIT: The hard way doesn't seem to be immediately effective... Thinking...

EDIT: It seems that some are able to be directly added to projects, im still working on figuring out how to add these to the viewport. But others (like "a boy and his kite") provide no such option. thinking...

Comment: What do you think the "hard way" is? Presumably you don't want that method as an answer but unless you tell us, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really put them in a central place where you can pick and choose from them. You have to copy them into the various projects you want to use them in. That's just how Unreal works (it's methods of packaging and traversing content assume a content root that is project-specific).

*Some* `uasset` files can sometimes be dragged, manually, from the filesystem. This is error prone and tedious, however.

The way you're intended to to it is from the Epic Launcher. Choose your Library tab. This will show you all your project and all your Marketplace-purchased content (under the Vault section). From there, click the "Add to Project" button and select the projects you want to migrate the content to. You cannot add the content to projects with mismatched engine versions.

Another option is to open the project that already has the content, or the sample project for the content if one is provided, right-click the content folder you want in the Content Browser and choose the "Migrate" option to move all the assets to another project of your choosing.

A third option is to create a new blank project and populate that project with all your desired content as above. [Then convert that project to a template.](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/Projects/CreatingTemplates/) That way you can just create a new project that as all the content you want available without having to repeat the hassle more than once.